# How to make a type property dependant on another?

Tags: typescript

I'm having a scenario where I want to create a type with two fields: *fields* and *requiredFields*. I want the *fields* type to be an array, where as the *requiredFields* should also be an array, but only allow strings that are defined in the *fields* array.

I essentially want something like this, but I can't figure out the type for the *requiredFields* property, as it depends on the *fields* property.

```
type Form = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
}

type MyObject = {
  fields: (keyof Form)[]
  requiredFields: ... // entry in fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
type Form = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
}

interface MyObject {
  fields: (keyof Form)[]
  requiredFields: Array<this['fields'][number]>
}

const foo: MyObject = {
  fields: ['age', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
  requiredFields: ['age']
} // ok

const bar: MyObject = {
  fields: ['age', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
  requiredFields: ['age', 'error']
} // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLZQLxQN4CgpQGYCWCAzsAHICGSEAXFKQgQHYDmOUANhaZdXQ8za4KLWlCYBXJACMICLAF8sWZsDl4KAY2gBZEAHlpAKwibgmdoQgcAJsToAKANYQQcPLERIAlAG0AuuwIEACOEkQQNjAE1nZ0AIIICBQgADzAABYExL4A5Fa2xLn%20vpIycv4AfIrKmnBMpPhwcHR6hiZmaBa4BXFQeSIQuQA0UPlEPFRDo7lck9TFw0Gh4cFRMYV0A6LFilAA9PtQcE619Y3SFAitBsam5ujYPRt929NjhCTkUyNjc98LfxLXDBMIRdaxez9XKDX65OQIRC7BQHI4IxBAA)

**Update**
You can use a function to infer an validate the argument:

```js
type MyObject<T extends string[]> = {
  fields: T
  requiredFields: Partial<[...T]> // entry in fields
}

const validate = <
  Field extends string,
  Fields extends Field[]
>(obj: MyObject<[...Fields]>) => {

}

const result = validate({
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
  requiredFields: ['firstName'] // ok
})

const result2 = validate({
  fields: ['lastName'],
  requiredFields: ['firstName'] // oerror
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmA8gIwFZQMYgDwBUZQAeIUAdgCYDOMlIATgJakDmA2gLoB8MAvDAN7AYMAGYMoAGyoAuGLiEw6UAI4BXBkvIAxcVMqyACgEM6IBkYnZWAOlu4uMAPSOCpemBhNRuqsAC+wMAYAPaktDAAbhYM5EYkvDDYCjqS5ATEZFQ09EzMADTJPtREJBTUKVIcwJwAFMFosggo6FhWttYVVFwAlLzcgv6BIWEgilCUqhKjfFESMXFQNYLCYqn6MKwA5GJ0tAByRgC2UJt5MJsSRvtHJ+wFwkpqGlDaRbJbO9fHm+xOLsEAa383SGoXCSgmUwATAlZvMSEsFKs9O8LlcQAdvncFI91JpOusPhovrc-jBglA6HRgnRgUA)

You can read more about function argument inference here
https://catchts.com/infer-arguments

Comment: Doesn't quite work, as I only want the requiredFields to be able to contain strings that are defined in the fields Array. In your solution I can remove the age from the fields array but still have it in my requiredFields array, without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using type parameters and functions to infer them, like captain-yossarian mentioned:

```
type Form = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
}

type MyObject<T extends keyof Form = keyof Form, U extends T = T> = {
    fields: T[]
    requiredFields: U[]
}

const asMyObject = <T extends keyof Form, U extends T>(t: MyObject<T, U>) => t

function acceptMyObject<T extends keyof Form, U extends T>(t: MyObject<T, U>) {
  // ...
}

acceptMyObject({
  fields: ["age", "firstName"],
  requiredFields: ["age"],
})

// Type '"something"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Form'.
const t0 = asMyObject({
  fields: ["age", "something"],
  requiredFields: ["age"],
})

// Type '"lastName"' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "age"'.
acceptMyObject({
  fields: ["age", "firstName"],
  requiredFields: ["age", "firstName", "lastName"],
})

function consumeMyObject(obj: MyObject) {
  // ...
}
```